# assistance with pagination wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

the pagination for this site no longer renders the posts when clicking to page 2 and so on. It only shows the first 5 on the posts page.
this is the code that im working with:

```php
<?php if($postcount > $postsperpage): ?>
    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
      <li <?php if($paged == 1 ){echo 'class="disabled"';} ?>><a href="<?= $siteurl ?>/category/news">First</a></li>
      <li <?php if($paged == 1 ){echo 'class="disabled"';} ?>><a href="<?= $siteurl ?>/category/news/page/<?= $paged - 1 ?>">Prev</a></li>
      <?php foreach(range(1,$pagecount) as $page): ?>
        <li <?php if($paged == $page ){echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="<?= $siteurl ?>/category/news/page/<?= $page ?>"><?= $page ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      <li <?php if($paged == $pagecount ){echo 'class="disabled"';} ?>><a href="<?= $siteurl ?>/category/news/page/<?= $paged + 1 ?>">Next</a></li>
      <li <?php if($paged == $pagecount ){echo 'class="disabled"';} ?>><a href="<?= $siteurl ?>/category/news/page/<?= $pagecount ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: hello what you want do actully.As I understand you have to prevent navigation links.

Comment: when I click on any of those links the pagination does not work, i added <li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
  <li><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?></li> which now works when I click on the links, it shows the posts from previous dates.

Comment: you have to create post object using WP_
Query and iterate as per your need.

Comment: thank you for you assistance

Comment: can you post full code??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- then the pagination links -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

**Explaination:**

Print Next Page and &larr (left arrow)

```
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
```

Print Previous Page &rarr( Right arrow)

```
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```